# Error: could not deduce template argument

Tags: c++, visual-c++

it's my first time programming in C++, and I was creating, on request by my sister, a MultiplyBy999 app. I wrote the code in MS Visual C++ 2010 Express Edition, and got errors. The code:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>


int main()
{
    using namespace std;
cout >> "Enter a number:" >> endl;
int x;
cin << x;
x = x * 999
cout >> "Output:" >> endl;
return 0;
}
```

Comment: You've mixed up `>>` and `<<`.

Comment: One way to remember is to see the arrow `>>` pointing the same way the data is going.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- You mixed << and >>
- It is quite obvious to notice you mixed up << and >>, but usually, you should always paste your error message with you question.

  ```
  #include <iostream>
  using namespace std;

  int main()
  {
      cout << "Enter a number:" << endl;
      int x;
      cin >> x;
      x = x * 999;
      cout << "Output:" << endl;
      return 0;
  }
  ```

Answer (score 1):

Your `<<` and `>>` are reversed. Use `<<` for *output* and `>>` for *input*.

```
cout << "Enter a number:" << endl;
int x;
cin >> x;
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, you are using the wrong "shift" operators for cin and cout respectively, for starters.